# Drupal Batch operation page fails with my theme

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules, drupal-themes

I have created a theme for Drupal, everything works fine, except for the Batch operations page.
Even the progess bar is not displayed.

Do I need to include any special tags in my theme to make the the Drupal Batch operations work.

Comment: This is totally an aside, but have you looked at the Zen theme? It's a base theme designed as a starting point for your own themes -- works really well!

Comment: I should have started with it. Thanks for the info. Will try that for the next one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't put these two lines in page.tpl.php header, I had coded the theme file from scratch.

```
<?php print $scripts ?>
<?php print $styles ?>
```

Once it is added Batch pages started working.